# Issue of using enum in Nest JS from package

Tags: npm, nestjs

I have a problem using with TypeScript enum in a Nest JS Application.

I have a monorepo (npm workspace) setup that contains some packages and some apps. One of the packages is the types package used to share types between FE and BE. Next JS (frontend) app can use every type, interface, and enums without any issue however, when I try to use any enum in the Nest JS app (types/interfaces works) the build/dev fails. FYI any enum loading locally is working perfectly. Please let me know if you know the problem.

Error

```
api:dev: Error: Cannot find module '@kaufsync-monorepo/types/user-type'
api:dev: Require stack:
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/user/entities/user.entity.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/user/user.service.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/company/company.service.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/product-category/product-category.service.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/product-category/product-category.module.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/product/product.module.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/modules/app.module.js
api:dev: - /Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/build/src/main.js
api:dev:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:955:15)
api:dev:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:803:27)
api:dev:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
api:dev:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
api:dev:     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/asifsaho/Projects/kaufsync-monorepo/apps/api/src/modules/user/entities/user.entity.ts:1:1)
api:dev:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
api:dev:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
api:dev:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
api:dev:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
api:dev:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? running into the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@kaufsync-monorepo/types/*": ["path/to/types/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Check typescript configuration in your app. If you're using TypeScript, check your tsconfig.json file.